# Django: populate form field with javascript array

Tags: javascript, django, forms, templates

I have a template where I plot some images and comments associated to the image.

I want to allow users to add comments to one image displayed directly in the template. Then, when the user fill its comment, I would like that all the other fields except the text are automatically filled.

Question: How to define the value of a form field with Javascript ?

Idiot example: `{{ form.field1.value }} = jsArray[0]`

Additional example:

HTML

```
<button onclick="setImage()">Fill image value</button>

<form method="post" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="image" id="id_image" value="" maxlength="30" readonly>
    <input type="hidden" name="user" id="id_user" {% if form.user.value != None %}value="{{ form.user.value|stringformat:'s' }}"{% endif %} maxlength="30" readonly>
    {{ form.text }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
  function setImage() {
      document.getElementById("id_image").value = imageObjectTable[0];
      //imageObjectTable[0] is one object of the model "ImageModel"
  }
```

Django - models.py

```
    class ImageModel(models.Model):
# Create your models here.
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(('image'),
                              max_length=IMAGE_FIELD_MAX_LENGTH,
                              upload_to='.')
    date_taken = models.DateTimeField(('date taken'),
                                      null=True,
                                      blank=True,
                                      help_text=('Date image was taken; is obtained from the image EXIF data.'))


class Comment(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(ImageModel, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Django - Forms.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('user','image', 'text', )
```

=> When I launch the JS function setImage, the value is well filled in the HTML, but when I submit the form, it is not working :(

Many thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution ... : the value expected in the django form is neither a string, neither the object concerned but an integer which relates the position of the choice (starting by 1 because 0 is the undefined choice).

So my first code was:

```
 document.getElementById("id_image").value = imageObjectTable[0];
```

The version which works is:

```
 document.getElementById("id_image").value = 1;
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming because you want to fill in a Django variable you need it on the back end after a form submit?

In that case usually, you'd fill in the HTML form field value with Javascript and let your form submission handle the rest.

You can get the ID of the field (assuming you haven't manually built the HTML) with `{{ form.field1.auto_id }}`

Then use the ID to select the document by id or use the js DOM query selector to prefill the value you want.

Comment: Hi Jason, many thanks for your answer. I have tried like that

      <form method="post" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="user" value="username">
        {{ form.image }}
        {{ form.text }}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>

However, my hand made input does not fill the model ... Did I write a bad code ?

Comment: Can you paste the javascript you refer to in the question? Your snippet doesn't really match the question.

Comment: Hum, maybe I need to reformulate. If I set the html form basically I would have:
      <form method="post" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.user }}
        {{ form.image }}
        {{ form.text }}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>

But, I want that:
 form.user is automacally set to the user connected
 form.image is set through a javascript function